# Why is "How to stop genetic algorithm population converging to a single value" not being answered

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted the question "[How to stop genetic algorithm population converging to a single value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87158/how-to-stop-genetic-algorithm-population-converging-to-a-single-value)" 11 days ago but it has received very little interest - only a single comment and my response to that comment.  How can I improve this question so that it actually gets some response from the community?

Comment: Have you consulted our [help pages](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)?

Comment: I didn't answer it because my own knowledge of it is limited (I've read some books and papers, and had some limited exposure to using GAs), so I left it for someone with better knowledge. While I wouldn't say it's off topic here, you may get a better response on a different SE site; perhaps scicomp.SE, or cs.SE or math.SE - there might be a greater concentration of people familiar with GA on one of those (check their help pages for what exactly is on topic).

Comment: @whuber I have seen that page, which is why I edited the question previously to update the things I had tried and reformat the question a bit.  If you see some other deficiency then please tell me.

Comment: I didn't answer because, like @Glen_b, I have very limited knowledge of genetic algorithms. In addition to the lists he suggested, you might look for a more specialized list.

Comment: @PeterFlom the only specialised list that comes to mind was the AI SE site but that never made it out of closed beta.

Comment: How about one of the ones mentioned [here http://www.genetic-programming.org/gpmailinglist.html]

Comment: @PeterFlom Genetic Algorithms and Genetic Programming are related but different topics.  Genetic Programming AFAIK is about finding the program that best solves a given problem.  The EC-Digest list on that page looks applicable, but not very busy.  cs.SE seems to be a better home for my question. I'll flag it for a move.